# Android-Audio Streaming From Pc

Tags: android

I am new to android.I want to play a video or audio file from my Pc(server) to the emulator(Client).To do this want should I have to do.I don't have any idea what should I have to do.I have to set Socket.I have to change any thing in Pc Side.What should I have to do.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly ambitious first project. But basically, you need to have a server running on your PC that will serve the media. Then, have an Android app connect to your media server and use Android's MediaPlayer class to play the audio/video. A detailed documentation of the MediaPlayer class can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). I can't find any authoritative documentation on what protocols are supported out of the box, but you should at least be able to get it working with RTSP, as documented [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ebb4ca5b298a8d92/00a515bbc5c1bd47), by running a VLC server on the PC.